# Developing a Medical Product Using AliExpress Modules

Tags: certification, medical

We are developing a medical product and we are using some modules that we got from AliExpress *(www.aliexpress.com)*.

They are really cheap and gave us the same results with the modules which we made with the obtained parts from Digikey and Mouser.

But we are worrying about if we will not be able to get the required CE Application to our medical product because of using Aliexpress modules.

The main question is: Even if the modules works the same (aliexpress modules and our modules made with Digikey parts), is it possible to fail to get the CE Application just because using Aliexpress modules instead of using proper parts from Digikey, Mouser or etc ?

Comment: Ok, medical devices and "we don't know whether we can use these suspicously cheap sourced modules" don't go together. Be careful. You'll hurt someone.

Comment: At least mention the name(s) of the products here, you know, for people who want to live.

Comment: It's your responsibility to ensure your product is compliant with the requirements of CE. And the proof of compliance has to be kept on file with some entity resident in the EU (e.g. a distributor). AFAIK your  supply chain and its integrity is up to you to vouch for.

Comment: Someone please write an answer in the same kind of Engrish we find in Aliexpress product descriptions. Also, how do you check voltage rating and dielectric quality on unmarked ceramic capacitors?

Comment: I suggest that you get copies of the pertinent regulations and start studying up.  Then hire someone whose gotten things approved before, and **listen to them**.  Because needing to ask on Stackexchange is a sign that you're going to be getting a *lot* of things wrong.  Even the modules you're getting from DigiKey and Mouser probably won't be considered reliable enough.  The point of 1st-world medical device regulations isn't that it's really inexpensive and works 98% of the time -- the point is that if it's life critical it works something like 99.999% of the time.

Comment: Do not do this. Why do you think medical devices are expensive and so well regulated... If you find out your device is killing people, will you be able to sleep ever again?

Comment: You sound like you've never heard of grey market parts. That's the difference between retailers like Digikey or Mouser and Ali-Express. Your parts could be real one order, and be counterfeit, or damaged the next.

Comment: **_WAIT! STOP!_** Are you trying to kill your patients with cheap Chinese parts you find on the internet?!? How do you all anticipate any support you all may have with your products? No, hire some real engineers that will make your medical devices fabricated on a professional level. This is absurd that you want to nose dive into product management without proper product development. You need support from suppliers and you need to know what you’re doing. Right it just sounds like you’re picking flowers off the ground and putting it into your own garden.

Comment: I don't really agree with the downvotes here, it's a good question, deserves a spot on the site and an answer.

Comment: @pipe I was torn, so I didn't vote – on one hand, this question really shows no research into what CE means whatsoever (-1), on the other hand, "what consequences does supply chain quality have for me as a vendor of medical devices" is a very nice question (even if OP really phrases this hamfistedly, +1).

Comment: Relax guys, getting products CE certified for medical device is a while lot harder than lab or domestic stuff. They'll need to engage a notified body to oversee it and it will have to be manufactured in a controlled and audited environment... Typically iso13485 accredited, which means they'll need to see evidence of supply chain integrity and so on... They'll fail to get anywhere without a ton of work and understanding. There are places in which this might be acceptable - where it cannot cause any foreseeable hazard, but I can't think of many examples where this would be the case.

Comment: I would consult with several 3rd party experts and choose 1.  e.g. https://www.intertek.com/medical/ce-marking/

Answer (score 6):

Ok, there's different things that go under the name of "CE". First of all, for a whole class of consumer electronics, being CE certified means that **you**, as importer or producer, guarantee that the device complies to regulations and is **safe**.

That just means you sign a letter that says you guarantee that. Yes, that makes you responsible for making sure your device is safe.

If you're using modules from suppliers that give you excellent documentation and make guarantees themselves, this becomes a lot easier. You really "only" need to make sure that the way you're using the modules is safe.

Now, when you buy from aliexpress and import directly from an anonymous seller (I dare you to track down your seller with a case of "this isn't like you promised" on aliexpress and get them to be legally responsible for what they deliver), you're on your own.

Say, you buy a power supply module from mouser. It comes with a datasheet you can reasonably trust, and it certifies it fulfills the isolation requirements for medical equipment (you're aware of these, right?). Great! You use that supply, you plug in the rest of your device, and you basically can't electrocute your patient. You can say that you did diligently make sure you don't kill anyone. Good job!

Now, you buy a very similar supply from aliexpress. It doesn't come with extensive PDFs that show the certification. The product page somewhere mentions it's "safe for medical", whatever that means. You build that. Someone sues you for gross negligence, because one of your devices malfunctioned and killed their daughter. The judge asks you to prove you've done sound engineering and chose safe components. You show them the screenshot of the aliexpress product page. You end up behind bars. Not so great a job.

---

Obviously, for medical devices, CE does entail a whole lot more regulations, and I know very few of these. When building a medical device, you'll definitely want to buy the services of someone who does know these regulations and has brought such a device to market before.